# Getting data from joined tables Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby, join, activerecord

In summary, I need to grab columns from three tables, which all are associated with each other through inbetween tables.

There are four cases with the data:
1. Has data in table A, has data in table B, has data in table C
2. Has data in table A, has data in table B, does not have data in table C
3. Has data in table A, does not have data in table B, has data in table C
4. Has data in table A, does not have in table B, does not have in table C

Is there a single active record query I can use to get the data for all these cases?  I cannot use join because the query dies if it come across a row missing any of the pieces.  I have tried .includes and .eager_load, but then it does not include the columns from table B or C.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think for this you need an _outer join_ which as far as I know is not what `.includes` does.

Comment: Please share some of the code you wrote so far. This will help everyone to understand your setup better.